# Aura:method and callback

Tags: aura

I am not able to understand Aura:method attribute and how it helps in making asynchronous callbacks.. I went through this [Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_function.htm) but was not able to understand its working.. Will be great help if anyone can provide docs for aura:method component and function type attribute in aura!? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aura:method is called synchronously. The trick to an [asynchronous return value](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cmp_methods_async.htm) is a callback, which is a Function:

```
<!-- c:auraMethod -->
<aura:component controller="SimpleServerSideController">
    <aura:method name="echo"
      description="Sample method with server-side call">
        <aura:attribute name="callback" type="Function" />
    </aura:method>

    <p>This component has an aura:method definition.</p>
</aura:component>
```

A Function is a normal JavaScript type that is a function.

```
var logMessage = function(param) { console.log(param); }
```

In this example, logMessage is a [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). You can do a number of interesting things with it:

```
logMessage("This is a message.")
logMessage.call(null, "This is another message.");
logMessage.apply(null, ["This is yet another message."]);
```

Also, if you want to formalize a reference with parameters:

```
var sayHelloWorld = logMessage.bind(null, "Hello World");
sayHelloWorld(); // outputs "Hello World"
```

The two links I included should answer any further questions you have.